# '/user/share/X11/conf.d' does not exist

Tags: xorg, manjaro, displaylink

I am a Manjaro KDE user trying to hook up my DisplayLink so that I can multi-screen and there is this line of code that will not let me pass GO.

```
'/user/share/X11/conf.d' does not exist
```

I have tried changing share to shar, or subbing with etc and nothing seems to work. I am wondering if the x11 is the issue, but since I am new at Manjaro, I have not a clue.

I would like to add that instead of user i did switch it to usr and tried the different combos of share/shar and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ditch Manjaro because using DisplayLink needs stuff installed from AUR and Manjaro's policy of delaying Arch packages will cause this to break constantly.

Then you need to install the driver for DisplayLink it's called evdi and it's in AUR

Instructions are here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/DisplayLink

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions for multiple screens with only one HDMI port on the computer then? Because I have done so much work with Manjaro, I would hate to restart with something else. Especially if that something else is Windows or Mac.

Comment: It was working to a point until I reached one segment and then hit a road block that I have no idea what to do with. It says GNU nano                                6.3 and then a bunch of options at the bottom that say things like ^G Help.

Comment: Arch is what Manjaro is "based" on. Just use Arch. Or if you need a GUI installer use EndevourOS it's Arch + an installer. 

If you can do it on Manjaro you can do it better on arch